# gdal translate -co, which options are available to PNG?

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, png

I can create a PNG with:

```
gdal_translate -of PNG -outsize 10% 10% image.bsq image.png
```

I see there is a `-co` (creation options) parameter I can pass to `gdal translate`. Where can I find which options are available for PNG?

Answer (score 3):

The short PNG driver manual is at http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html. Png is an uncommon format for geospatial images. The same lossless compression method is usually applied by creating a deflate compressed TIFF. Then you have options for "predictor" and "zlevel" http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html. For setting transparent color I would try to run gdal_translate with the `-a_nodata` option.